# Does apple mind you using that striped table view background in your own views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface, interface-builder

The ones they use with grouped table view.

I'm using a table view that links to another view that has text on it. To make it look less 'plain' I wanted to add that striped background and then put something like a white 'text box' on that.

Do they allow it to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they do allow that.  I've done so in an application that has been updated and re-approved several times over.  The pattern is available as `[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]`.

Answer (score 3):

sure.

For more details you may want to look at [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: +1 For referencing the HIG and providing a link. However, there's a reason they're called "guidelines". Following the HIG will generally result in nice-looking apps. Unless there is a compelling reason to violate the HIG, and the result is provably better, don't. Apple endorses the HIG and recommends use of system-wide controls so the user experience is more consistent.

Comment: Good point, there are definitely Apps that "break the rules" and have incredibly elegant interfaces, but these guidelines are a good starting point for someone jumping into App development.

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't mind. Why would they?

Comment: I just thought as they might only want that background to be associated with table views. As somtimes they can picky about this type of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a problem.

If you start doing something more complicated than a text box, say a button that you click that slides in another view controller, you're going to be duplicating a lot of UITableView/UITableViewController code, and you're better off just creating a UITableView with a controller and couple of singleton UITableViewCells in your nib file.